# ¿Se puede cazar una gamba?

Tags: significado, animales, diferencias-entre-palabras

Ayer me propusieron ir a cazar gambas. De primeras, respondí que las gambas no se cazan, se pescan; a lo cual la otra persona me replicó que no, que pescar es solo para coger peces con la caña.
Y entonces, como tantas otras veces, empezamos a darle vueltas.

- Por una parte, en principio todo lo que sea capturar algo marino sería "pescar"... y sin embargo decimos "cazar ballenas", no "pescar ballenas". ¿Quizá es por el tamaño? ¿Los animales marinos grandes se cazan y los pequeños se pescan?
- Pero hay ballenas que no son mucho más grandes que un tiburón, y sin embargo no me consta que se diga más "cazar tiburones" que "pescar tiburones". ¿Quizá es cierto que "pescar" se usa solo con peces, y no con mamíferos?
- Pero cuando un delfín o un pingüino se enganchan en las redes de arrastre, no decimos que los hemos cazado, sino que los hemos pescado. ¿Quizá es cierto que "pescar" es solo cuando se emplean útiles de pesca, como una caña, una red o un salabre? Pero entonces que alguien me explique lo del cazamariposas...

Al final, establecimos que la diferencia estaba en que la caza es activa, mientras que la pesca es pasiva: si soy yo el que persigue al animal, sea una ballena, una mariposa o una gamba, estoy cazando; mientras que si me limito a esperar a que los animales se queden atrapados en mi anzuelo o red para sacarlos después, estoy pescando.

¿Es correcta esta interpretación? ¿Se pueden cazar las gambas?

Comment: En catalán las setas se cazan :D De hecho hay un programa en la tele llamado exactamente así: [_Caçadors de bolets_](https://www.ccma.cat/tv3/cacadors-de-bolets/)

Comment: Creo que las ballenas no se **pescan** por que no son **peces**. Son mamíferos. Creo que debe existir relación etimológica entre pez y pesca. Obvio esto no explica lo de las gambas :-)

Comment: Pescar es sacar algo del agua. Solo se me ocurre un animal que se cace en el agua: la ballena, como has dicho, y las ballenas se capturan en el agua sin sacarlas de ella. No sé si tiene algo que ver, en mi cabeza tiene sentido

Comment: @DGaleano por esa relación etimológica, las gambas se [mariscan](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ORHj977). :-)

Comment: @Charlie Como siempre... Gran hallazgo. Las gambas son mariscos y los mariscos se mariscan.

Answer (score 3):

En general diría que estoy de acuerdo con la interpretación final, es decir, que los siguientes puntos aportan a que elijamos una palabra u otra:

- ***pescar***: uso de caña o red, espera pasiva, captura de peces, moluscos o crustáceos, captura de animales más bien pequeños;
- ***cazar***: uso de armas, persecución o ataque, captura de mamíferos o aves, captura de animales grandes.

Pero hay excepciones. Por ejemplo, mayormente se emplea "caza de ballenas" pero no es difícil encontrar referencias a "pesca de ballenas". Cuando se usa un arpón para capturar un pez (generalmente en aguas poco profundas) se habla de pesca aunque se emplee un arma arrojadiza (contra la idea de que la pesca es pasiva).

Quizá un punto adicional pueda ser que la caza puede ser dirigida a la eliminación de un animal peligroso o la captura para estudio, y por eso se percibe (yo al menos) una diferencia entre "cazar tiburones" y "pescar tiburones": los primeros se cazan por el solo hecho de matarlos y/o estudiarlos, los segundos se pescan para consumirlos como comida.

Con las mariposas no hay dudas de que se cazan porque, aunque sea con red (y sean animales pequeños y que no se comen), no son acuáticos y además hay que perseguirlas.

Con las gambas, más allá de que se muevan y traten de escapar, creo que corresponde sin duda decir "pescar", porque funcionan para todos los fines prácticos como peces y se capturan con red. Aunque haya que perseguirlas, no es el mismo tipo de persecución que se da con una ballena capturada a arponazos: se sigue al banco de gambas (o como se llame), se arroja la red para que caigan en ella y luego se levanta la red. (La persecución está separada de la captura.)

Comment: Yo diría que la estás intentando pescar con la mano. :) No, la pesca de arrastre no es pasiva, pero no es el mismo tipo de acción directa/dirigida que arrojar un arpón o una flecha o disparar un tiro.